# Firebase 3 - Can't retrieve data from database (Web)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a webapp using `Firebase 3` (the latest version) for the first time but I'm having troubles with `retrieving data` on my page.

I've created a `NodeJS` test app from `Heroku`, then I'm trying to retrieve my data in JSON format (ref's path goes to my data array) saved in my Firebase `realtime database`.
I've followed the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data), but without results.

**Here's my code:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "*******",
    authDomain: "*******",
    databaseURL: "*******",
    storageBucket: "*******",
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.database().ref('my/path/to/data').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log('kk'); //no log in the console
});

</script>
```

There are no errors in the console, but no results too. It seems so simple to do but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been working in my application:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref(`/database/path`)
  .once('value')
  .then((snapshot) => { console.log('hi') });
```

Comment: I got this error in console: firebase.js:442 Uncaught (in promise) Error: permission_denied at /my/path/to/data: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Comment: Check the permissions for DB access as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but the below code works.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid + '/<your-object-name>').once('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log('A----->');
    console.log('snapshot', JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));
});
```

Replace `<your-object-name>` with your object.